# Can internet browsers catch keys pressed in other programs?

Tags: theory

I need a very simple text editor that will magically stop videos playing in the background in different window (internet browser). Of course the editor won't lose its focus :)

Is it even possible?

Because at first it looks like some kind of security threat.

Let's say I want to hit space twice very fast and it will "mean" one space to the browser (because space usually stops a video, for example on YT, and I will never need double space in my editor)?

Any ideas how to achieve that? I guess it might be quite easy with dedicated browser plugins?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.

But you need browser's API or plugin for catching event and dispatching to a site.

Or you can go with hacks like controlling processes.

Also you can fork Open Source browser.